# AVD not getting created using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kvm, android-virtual-device

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit system. I am trying to create an AVD using the AVD Manager of Android Studio but am unable to do so. The procedure seems pretty straightforward, so I don't  where I am going wrong. Let me take you through the exact problem.
So, I select AVD Manager (Tools->Android->AVD Manager) from Android Studio and the following screen pops up.
[Check image here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4343brBNGLoYVlSbVJVV2N2YVk/view?usp=sharing)

I go on to select the device, System Image, Skin type etc. In this case, it is a Google Nexus 5, API level 21 and System Image x86.
[Check Image here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4343brBNGLoMXpIQ1pCZUNJWWc/view?usp=sharing)

Finally, one all the features have been set, I select "Finish" and nothing happens. I go back to the screen shown in the first picture and there is no new device added.
I have installed KVM as per the instructions given in the Official Ubuntu Documentation (can't post link as I don't have 10 reputation points) and the installation was successful.
I have tried searching for this problem but I don't seem to be getting any answers. What could be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: i am running in the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it I think you did not properly installed KVM. Try this :

Use the below command to check whether the KVM is installed in the machine or not,

```
kvm-ok
```

Output:

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Output like the below means,

INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used

In this scenario need to install KVM using the below command,

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

It worked for me

Cheers